# How to extract the coordinate of the shaded region when LineString and circular Polygon geometries intersects?

Tags: python, geometry, gis, geopandas, shapely

I have geometries, as shown in the figure.
three circular Polygon geometries (circle1,circle2 and circle3) and nineteen LineStrimgs (line0,line1,...,line18).
I want to extract the coordinates of the grey-shaded region (area between circle1 and circle, which has been equally divided by the passing line strings) in the figure. Here I only shaded three areas, but I want to extract the coordinates of all the similar regions individually as a list.

How can I do that? If the solution could use the functionalities of geopandas and shapely, it would be great.
I tried to interpolate the method between the Linestring and polygons, but there was no use at all.  Could you help me?
[image]

Comment: This is simple geometry.  Presumably, you have the center point of the circles and the radius of the circles.  You have 36 pie segments here, so the area of each the circle 3 chunks is `(circle 3 area - circle 2 area) / 36`.  You can get the coordinates through trigonometry.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you ask.  Note that I have hardcoded the 3 radii, and I have not adjusted for the center point.

```
import math
import os


cir1 = []
cir2 = []
cir3 = []
r1 = 80
r2 = 100
r3 = 120

for theta in range(0,360,10):
    x1 = r1 * math.cos( math.radians( theta ) )
    y1 = r1 * math.sin( math.radians( theta ) )
    cir1.append( (x1, y1) )
    x2 = r2 * math.cos( math.radians( theta ) )
    y2 = r2 * math.sin( math.radians( theta ) )
    cir2.append( (x2, y2) )
    x3 = r3 * math.cos( math.radians( theta ) )
    y3 = r3 * math.sin( math.radians( theta ) )
    cir3.append( (x3, y3) )

cir1.append(cir1[0])
cir2.append(cir2[0])
cir3.append(cir3[0])

inner = []
outer = []
for i in range(36):
    inner.append( (cir1[i][0],cir1[i][1], cir2[i][0],cir2[i][1], cir2[i+1][0],cir2[i+1][1], cir1[i+1][0],cir1[i+1][1] ))
    outer.append( (cir2[i][0],cir2[i][1], cir3[i][0],cir3[i][1], cir3[i+1][0],cir3[i+1][1], cir2[i+1][0],cir2[i+1][1] ))

print( "Coords of innter ring segments:" )
for pts in inner:
    print( "(%f,%f), (%f,%f), (%f,%f), (%f,%f)" % pts )

print( "Coords of outer ring segments:" )
for pts in outer:
    print( "(%f,%f), (%f,%f), (%f,%f), (%f,%f)" % pts )
```

Output:

```
Coords of innter ring segments:
(80.000000,0.000000), (100.000000,0.000000), (98.480775,17.364818), (78.784620,13.891854)
(78.784620,13.891854), (98.480775,17.364818), (93.969262,34.202014), (75.175410,27.361611)
(75.175410,27.361611), (93.969262,34.202014), (86.602540,50.000000), (69.282032,40.000000)
(69.282032,40.000000), (86.602540,50.000000), (76.604444,64.278761), (61.283555,51.423009)
(61.283555,51.423009), (76.604444,64.278761), (64.278761,76.604444), (51.423009,61.283555)
(51.423009,61.283555), (64.278761,76.604444), (50.000000,86.602540), (40.000000,69.282032)
(40.000000,69.282032), (50.000000,86.602540), (34.202014,93.969262), (27.361611,75.175410)
(27.361611,75.175410), (34.202014,93.969262), (17.364818,98.480775), (13.891854,78.784620)
(13.891854,78.784620), (17.364818,98.480775), (0.000000,100.000000), (0.000000,80.000000)
(0.000000,80.000000), (0.000000,100.000000), (-17.364818,98.480775), (-13.891854,78.784620)
(-13.891854,78.784620), (-17.364818,98.480775), (-34.202014,93.969262), (-27.361611,75.175410)
(-27.361611,75.175410), (-34.202014,93.969262), (-50.000000,86.602540), (-40.000000,69.282032)
(-40.000000,69.282032), (-50.000000,86.602540), (-64.278761,76.604444), (-51.423009,61.283555)
(-51.423009,61.283555), (-64.278761,76.604444), (-76.604444,64.278761), (-61.283555,51.423009)
(-61.283555,51.423009), (-76.604444,64.278761), (-86.602540,50.000000), (-69.282032,40.000000)
(-69.282032,40.000000), (-86.602540,50.000000), (-93.969262,34.202014), (-75.175410,27.361611)
(-75.175410,27.361611), (-93.969262,34.202014), (-98.480775,17.364818), (-78.784620,13.891854)
(-78.784620,13.891854), (-98.480775,17.364818), (-100.000000,0.000000), (-80.000000,0.000000)
(-80.000000,0.000000), (-100.000000,0.000000), (-98.480775,-17.364818), (-78.784620,-13.891854)
(-78.784620,-13.891854), (-98.480775,-17.364818), (-93.969262,-34.202014), (-75.175410,-27.361611)
(-75.175410,-27.361611), (-93.969262,-34.202014), (-86.602540,-50.000000), (-69.282032,-40.000000)
(-69.282032,-40.000000), (-86.602540,-50.000000), (-76.604444,-64.278761), (-61.283555,-51.423009)
(-61.283555,-51.423009), (-76.604444,-64.278761), (-64.278761,-76.604444), (-51.423009,-61.283555)
(-51.423009,-61.283555), (-64.278761,-76.604444), (-50.000000,-86.602540), (-40.000000,-69.282032)
(-40.000000,-69.282032), (-50.000000,-86.602540), (-34.202014,-93.969262), (-27.361611,-75.175410)
(-27.361611,-75.175410), (-34.202014,-93.969262), (-17.364818,-98.480775), (-13.891854,-78.784620)
(-13.891854,-78.784620), (-17.364818,-98.480775), (-0.000000,-100.000000), (-0.000000,-80.000000)
(-0.000000,-80.000000), (-0.000000,-100.000000), (17.364818,-98.480775), (13.891854,-78.784620)
(13.891854,-78.784620), (17.364818,-98.480775), (34.202014,-93.969262), (27.361611,-75.175410)
(27.361611,-75.175410), (34.202014,-93.969262), (50.000000,-86.602540), (40.000000,-69.282032)
(40.000000,-69.282032), (50.000000,-86.602540), (64.278761,-76.604444), (51.423009,-61.283555)
(51.423009,-61.283555), (64.278761,-76.604444), (76.604444,-64.278761), (61.283555,-51.423009)
(61.283555,-51.423009), (76.604444,-64.278761), (86.602540,-50.000000), (69.282032,-40.000000)
(69.282032,-40.000000), (86.602540,-50.000000), (93.969262,-34.202014), (75.175410,-27.361611)
(75.175410,-27.361611), (93.969262,-34.202014), (98.480775,-17.364818), (78.784620,-13.891854)
(78.784620,-13.891854), (98.480775,-17.364818), (100.000000,0.000000), (80.000000,0.000000)
Coords of outer ring segments:
(100.000000,0.000000), (120.000000,0.000000), (118.176930,20.837781), (98.480775,17.364818)
(98.480775,17.364818), (118.176930,20.837781), (112.763114,41.042417), (93.969262,34.202014)
(93.969262,34.202014), (112.763114,41.042417), (103.923048,60.000000), (86.602540,50.000000)
(86.602540,50.000000), (103.923048,60.000000), (91.925333,77.134513), (76.604444,64.278761)
(76.604444,64.278761), (91.925333,77.134513), (77.134513,91.925333), (64.278761,76.604444)
(64.278761,76.604444), (77.134513,91.925333), (60.000000,103.923048), (50.000000,86.602540)
(50.000000,86.602540), (60.000000,103.923048), (41.042417,112.763114), (34.202014,93.969262)
(34.202014,93.969262), (41.042417,112.763114), (20.837781,118.176930), (17.364818,98.480775)
(17.364818,98.480775), (20.837781,118.176930), (0.000000,120.000000), (0.000000,100.000000)
(0.000000,100.000000), (0.000000,120.000000), (-20.837781,118.176930), (-17.364818,98.480775)
(-17.364818,98.480775), (-20.837781,118.176930), (-41.042417,112.763114), (-34.202014,93.969262)
(-34.202014,93.969262), (-41.042417,112.763114), (-60.000000,103.923048), (-50.000000,86.602540)
(-50.000000,86.602540), (-60.000000,103.923048), (-77.134513,91.925333), (-64.278761,76.604444)
(-64.278761,76.604444), (-77.134513,91.925333), (-91.925333,77.134513), (-76.604444,64.278761)
(-76.604444,64.278761), (-91.925333,77.134513), (-103.923048,60.000000), (-86.602540,50.000000)
(-86.602540,50.000000), (-103.923048,60.000000), (-112.763114,41.042417), (-93.969262,34.202014)
(-93.969262,34.202014), (-112.763114,41.042417), (-118.176930,20.837781), (-98.480775,17.364818)
(-98.480775,17.364818), (-118.176930,20.837781), (-120.000000,0.000000), (-100.000000,0.000000)
(-100.000000,0.000000), (-120.000000,0.000000), (-118.176930,-20.837781), (-98.480775,-17.364818)
(-98.480775,-17.364818), (-118.176930,-20.837781), (-112.763114,-41.042417), (-93.969262,-34.202014)
(-93.969262,-34.202014), (-112.763114,-41.042417), (-103.923048,-60.000000), (-86.602540,-50.000000)
(-86.602540,-50.000000), (-103.923048,-60.000000), (-91.925333,-77.134513), (-76.604444,-64.278761)
(-76.604444,-64.278761), (-91.925333,-77.134513), (-77.134513,-91.925333), (-64.278761,-76.604444)
(-64.278761,-76.604444), (-77.134513,-91.925333), (-60.000000,-103.923048), (-50.000000,-86.602540)
(-50.000000,-86.602540), (-60.000000,-103.923048), (-41.042417,-112.763114), (-34.202014,-93.969262)
(-34.202014,-93.969262), (-41.042417,-112.763114), (-20.837781,-118.176930), (-17.364818,-98.480775)
(-17.364818,-98.480775), (-20.837781,-118.176930), (-0.000000,-120.000000), (-0.000000,-100.000000)
(-0.000000,-100.000000), (-0.000000,-120.000000), (20.837781,-118.176930), (17.364818,-98.480775)
(17.364818,-98.480775), (20.837781,-118.176930), (41.042417,-112.763114), (34.202014,-93.969262)
(34.202014,-93.969262), (41.042417,-112.763114), (60.000000,-103.923048), (50.000000,-86.602540)
(50.000000,-86.602540), (60.000000,-103.923048), (77.134513,-91.925333), (64.278761,-76.604444)
(64.278761,-76.604444), (77.134513,-91.925333), (91.925333,-77.134513), (76.604444,-64.278761)
(76.604444,-64.278761), (91.925333,-77.134513), (103.923048,-60.000000), (86.602540,-50.000000)
(86.602540,-50.000000), (103.923048,-60.000000), (112.763114,-41.042417), (93.969262,-34.202014)
(93.969262,-34.202014), (112.763114,-41.042417), (118.176930,-20.837781), (98.480775,-17.364818)
(98.480775,-17.364818), (118.176930,-20.837781), (120.000000,0.000000), (100.000000,0.000000)
```